# bootstrap columns sit on top eachother

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im a rookie with bootstrap. I'm trying to have the main content to the left and a side column to the right. For mobile view I want the right side column to go under the main content.

No matter what I try the side column is either directly ontop the main content column or it sits to the right but is still ontop of the main content column.

[image]

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
        <h4>About</h4>
        <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-module">
        <h4>Archives</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">March 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">February 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">January 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">December 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">November 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">October 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">September 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">August 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">July 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">June 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">May 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">April 2013</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-module">
        <h4>Elsewhere</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

<!-- I'm using ruby on rails so 'yeild' is where the main content shows -->
 <div class="col-sm-9"> <%= yield %> </div>
```

This seems like a fairly common basic thing to do in bootsrap so its frustrating that I cant get it. Whats going wrong?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc334zf0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct markup. Always wrap columns inside a row div. Also you were using an offset where it was not needed. Using `col-xs-12` will take the whole width of mobile screen which will result the left side bar to go under it:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- I'm using ruby on rails so 'yeild' is where the main content shows -->
 <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12"> <%= yield %> </div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
        <h4>About</h4>
        <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-module">
        <h4>Archives</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">March 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">February 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">January 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">December 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">November 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">October 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">September 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">August 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">July 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">June 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">May 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">April 2013</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-module">
        <h4>Elsewhere</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I added a fiddle but you had already answered by the time I linked in in the question

Comment: Glad it helped @user3234020